# How do I hide/unhide a column when I uncheck a checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny

I just learning Shiny and I have data going to a tableOutput.

I have 3 checkbox selections: 'CarA', 'CarB', 'CarC'. My table out put gives me the number of car sales for the year by county.

My desired actions and outcomes are:

- **Action**: uncheck CarA. **Result**: table renders only columns County, Year, CarB, CarC.
- **Action**: uncheck CarB. **Result**: table renders only columns County, Year, CarA, CarC.
- **Action**: uncheck CarC. **Result**: table renders only columns County, Year, CarA, CarB.
- **Action**: uncheck CarA, CarB, Car C. **Result**: table renders only columns County, Year.

My data is in a .csv file named data.csv.

```
county <- read.csv("data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

County,Year,CarA,CarB,CarC
Allen,2014,8,36,49
Allen,2015,15,45,45
Allen,2016,22,54,24
Allen,2017,9,32,61
Allen,2018,16,88,98
Alon,2014,12,66,11
Alon,2015,45,84,19
Alon,2016,35,23,65
Alon,2017,32,124,35
Alon,2018,65,25,95
Brome,2014,51,36,84
Brome,2015,12,48,12
Brome,2016,48,95,36
Brome,2017,65,64,18
Brome,2018,65,21,65
Catgus,2014,34,95,17
Catgus,2015,62,36,36
Catgus,2016,86,59,26
Catgus,2017,88,85,35
Catgus,2018,15,32,32
Cay,2014,26,84,64
Cay,2015,45,12,85
Cay,2016,84,36,38
Cay,2017,69,18,9
Cay,2018,24,35,168
```

Code:

```
#carsales
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel('Car Sales:'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("county", label = h4("Select a County:"),
                  choices = county$County),
      checkboxGroupInput("Category", label = h4("Category"), 
                         choices = list("CarA", "CarB", "CarC"),
                         selected = list('CarA', 'CarB', 'CarC'))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("cardate")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$cardate <- renderTable({
    countyfilter <- subset(county, county$County == input$county)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You seem to have attempted to clarify/modify your question by editing my answer. Please specify the question parameters in the question otherwise it'll be very confusing for anyone who shows up late

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. Not sure what kept you from finishing it up. Ask if you need clarifications

```
output$cardate <- renderTable({
countyfilter <- subset(county, county$County == input$county)
countyfilter[,c('County','Year', input$Category)]
 })
```